# Sending messages to another microservice with kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices

Quick question. Is there a way to send a message from a microservice using a kafka and receive a message on another microservice? I've seen some articles on github, dzone, etc, but everyone is using Docker which is not supported on my PC (I'm a Windows 10 Home loser :)
and the docker toolbox is ...

Thanks for the help.

Regards.

Comment: `Is there a way to send a message from a microservice using a kafka and receive a message on another microservice?` YES!

Comment: Also, you can run kafka manually without using Docker.

Comment: Yes, I try this way but receive message only in one listener. Add ids to listeners and restart kafka server fixed this. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

"Microservice" != Docker

Yes, you can use Kafka to communicate between any two applications, given there are compatible Kafka clients